# Are Nettops silent (fanless)?

Tags: fan, standards, silent-cooling, nettop

As Nettops are close, non-modular products, image evidence is lacking and from a bit of reading I got unclear data. Some models are clearly described as "fanless" but I can't generalize for all models.

Are Nettops silent (fanless)? Is there any standardization?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't think I've seen a netbook or nettop in ages  - and I suspect there's no real standardisation.

Comment: What makes you think there's standarization for having no fans? That would be one of the most pointless standards ever introduced. You can just google "nettop with fans" or "nettop with cooling" to find models that have fans.

Comment: Well I just thought that after 40 years of personal computers (experience and technological advancements) people would start to evaluate quietness in such a level that it would be a standard. A quality standard if not a safety one.

Comment: I'm sure people value their machines living longer much more than almost complete silence. Also, fan technologies develop together with PCs. They can be very quiet if your machine is not overheating due to old paste, dust or other factors.

Comment: Oh I have a few fanless/completely silent and very quiet boxen. They're not netboxen though :D

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nettop seems to think they died a death in 2015

Comment: @Destroy666 I don't think it must be the case that machines would live longer because of a fan. I have tried many machines with many "silent" CPU cooling, all were too loud for me... I would prefer a not high-end PC which is totally fanless, but there is a almost just no such thing with **current** technology.

Comment: @Destroy666 https://www.amazon.com/Mini-Computers/b/ref=dp_bc_aui_C_5?ie=UTF8&node=13896591011 take a look here, it doesn't seem to me that this concept died in 2015... Although, I never bought a nettop and don't really know what's going on.

Comment: Of course it mostly depends on how you handle your device and e.g. how often you clean it. But fans are much more efficient for now, there aren't too many models of e.g. laptops that are fanless. Back to the topic - still not quite sure why you asked the question. Just to avoid reading this spec of nettops? Or to know if a nettop that doesn't specify anything is fanless? Either way, pretty sure this question won't help you as this definitely isn't 100% followed standard.

Comment: I don't know why you thought I might not want to read nettops specs... Not withstanding the fact which I wrote here that some models are clearly described as fanless, indeed I just wanted to know if a nettop that doesn't specify anything about fans is fanless...

Comment: I don't buy a computer only because it's fanless or not, I take into account many specs and quite frankly I believe anyone else does.